# D365 CRM Model Driven App's Audit History Error when embedding a Canvas App

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, powerapps-canvas, power-platform, powerapps-modeldriven

Working on a Model Driven App using D365 Customer Service Module and when we add/embed a Canvas App we're getting a Server Error application when we viewing the **Audit History** (Highlighted Below).

The Server Error disappears and the Audit History appears when we remove the Canvas App.

Does anyone knows how to resolve this issue?

[image: D365 Audit History]

[image]

Canvas App is embedded to the right See "Appointment Availability Dashboard"

Comment: does this happen for systemadmin or normal user?

Comment: Can your share some details about network trace in DevTools of browser?

Comment: @AnkUser any user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have managed to solve this by adding the Canvas App to the Model Driven App using and HTML Web Resource instead of directly adding the Canvas App to the Model Driven App. This means the Canvas app presented as an IFRAME within the area we want to display.
I honestly cannot tell why this solve the audit history error. This is more of a work-around.
Hope this helps for anyone having this annoying error.